# Java Swing gridLayout issue

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout

I just cant get this to appear the way i want, im exhausted trying gridlayout, gridbaglayout, borderlayout etc...

plz i need help

[image]

this is what i did so far

```
    panneauEst = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

    zoneTexte = new JTextArea("LIVRES", 45, 50);
    scroller= new JScrollPane(zoneTexte);
    scroller.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 580));
    scroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    EcouteurBoutons btnEcouteur = new EcouteurBoutons();

    btnTrierCote = new JButton("Trier par cote");
    btnTrierCote.addActionListener(btnEcouteur);
    btnTrierTitre = new JButton("Trier par titre");
    btnRechercheCote = new JButton("Rechercher par cote");
    btnRechercheTitre = new JButton("Rechercher par titre");
    btnFusion = new JButton("Fusion");
    btnQuitter = new JButton("Quitter");

    panneauEst.add(scroller);

    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15104630/java-swing-gridlayout-issue
    this.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 2));
    this.add(panneauEst);
    this.add(btnTrierCote);
    this.add(btnTrierTitre);
    this.add(btnRechercheCote);
    this.add(btnRechercheTitre);
    this.add(btnFusion);
    this.add(btnQuitter);
```

Comment: That's very nice.  And how are expected to know what it is you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Have you thought about possibly doing 2 panels rather than just one? One panel with a `GridLayout(1,2)` and another possibly being `GridLayout(6,1)`? I'll let you determine what to do with those.

Comment: i don't think i can, my teacher didnt declare 2 jpanels in the diagram :(

Comment: @Pierre-lucG. Your teacher is using (at least) 2 containers.  A `JFrame`, a `JScrollPane` and what ever the buttons "might" be laid out on.  There is no (easy) way to make this with a single layout manager

Answer (score 1):

You need to use compound containers/layouts

Start with 3 containers.  The parent container, the `JScrollPane`/`JTable` and something like a `JPanel`

- Set the parent containers layout to `BorderLayout`.  Add the
  `JScrollPane`/`JTable` to it, at the `CENTER` position... `add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);`
- Create a new `JPanel` and set it's layout to `GridLayout(0, 1)`
- Add your buttons to this panel
- Add this panel to the `EAST` position of the parent container... `add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.EAST)`

Comment: i edited my code to show more of what i did, i think i will ask the teacher if its possible to add another jpanel, cuz its seems the preoper way to do it